# django inline modelform foreign key related values

Tags: python, django, django-1.8, inline-formset

I'm just starting playing with django. I read the documentation and similar questions here but I couldn't find a solution, probably I'm missing something really obvious or approaching the issue in the wrong way

I have the following model:

```
class Interview(models.Model):  
    nickname  = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False)

class Question(models.Model):
    phrase = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)

class Answer(models.Model): 
    [...]
    interview = models.ForeignKey(Interview,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)  
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False)
    code = models.CharField( max_length=1, choices=CODE_CHOICES, null=True)
```

the phrase field in the question could contain a '*' and when displaying the questions I would like it to be replaced with the interview's nickname.

This is easy in the view to display results:

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(interview=interview_obj)
for a in answers:
    a.question.phrase = a.question.phrase.replace('*',a.interview.nickname)
return render(request, 'results.html', {'answers': answers })
```

Anyway I'm not able to do the same with the formset. The following obviously does not work but I didn't find a way to achieve what I want:

```
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    code = ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer,attrs={'required': 'true'}), choices=Answer.CODE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['code']
```

in view:

```
AnswerFormset = inlineformset_factory(Question,Answer,form=AnswerForm,fields=['code'],extra=0)
answer_list = Answer.objects.filter(interview=interview_obj)
for a in answers:
    a.question.phrase = a.question.phrase.replace('*',a.interview.nickname)
formset = AnswerFormset(queryset=answer_list)
return render(request, 'interview.html', { 'formset' : formset, })
```